# java desktop "ajax" existe?

Tags: java, aplicação-desktop

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de retorna o valor para minha aplicação java desktop todo momento que um valor for adiciona a uma tabela.
Algo parecido com ajax para navegador.

Por ex. Temos a tabela pedidos e a cada registro que for adicionado a ela minha tela da aplicação seja atualizada exibindo esse valor (sem necessitar atualizar manualmente a tela ou ter que fecha-la e abri-la novamente).

Entenderam minha duvida? não sei como pesquisar por isso? alguém já passou por isso e pode me dar uma luz?

Comment: Sim, é possivel. Basta você atualizar o tablemodel do seu jtable assim que a inserção for feita, desta forma, toda vez que excluir, editar ou adicionar algum item na tabela, o tablemodel irá atualizar tambem. Veja [**este exemplo**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TablewithacustomTableModel.htm), tente editar os nomes.

Comment: Isso quando minha aplicação envia o valor, mas quando o valor é inserido no banco por um terceiro (Não sendo eu)... existe alguma forma?

Comment: Ficar "ouvindo" a tabela e assim q for adicionado algum valor me retornar esse valor?

Comment: Terceiro? Aplicacao desktop costuma ter sua propria base junto com a aplicacao, sua base é remota?

Comment: Sim, o valor será inserido por android no banco e minha aplicação deve exibir o valor

Comment: Será assim, o app no android envia um pedido com produtos para o banco de dados e minha aplicação desktop será o balcão, o qual deve exibir o pedido assim que ele é cadastrado no banco.

Comment: É um aplicativo desktop e um app android compartilhando uma base remota?

Comment: Bom, para este caso eu desconheço algum listerner que monitore sem precisar ser executado manualmente. Talvez usando alguma rotina, mas é melhor esperar alguem com mais expertise te ajudar.

Comment: blz, obrigado @DiegoFelipe

Comment: Se souber um pouco de inglês, veja este problema bem parecido com o seu no [**SOen**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351530/how-to-update-changed-data-into-the-database-by-using-jtable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use um Timer para refazer as consultas e/ou a conexão e/ou seus JTables;

Algo como

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
// (...)

Timer timer = new Timer(0, new ActionListener() {

   @Override
   public void actionRefresh(ActionEvent e) {
      updateRecords();
   }
});

timer.setDelay(30000); // refresh a cada 30 segundos
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 7):

Existem várias formas de resolver a sincronização entre vários clientes de uma fonte de dados. Alguns são simples e pouco eficientes, outros eficientes porém complexos. Vou citar duas abordagens.

## Verificação periódica

A resposta do Marcos usa esta técnica. Nela você crie um `Timer` ou algum objeto que execute em intervalos regulares, onde então você atualize os valores a partir do servidor.

Este é o método mais simples e menos eficiente. Se houver muitos dados, o sistema vai ficar bloqueado frequentemente e irritar o usuário. Além disso, vai transferir muitos dados desnecessariamente, se eles não mudaram entre uma execução e outra. Esta técnica é inviável se você precisa de atualizações em "tempo real".

Uma forma de melhorar um pouco isso seria executar uma consulta mais leve para verificar se houve alguma mudança. Por exemplo:

- Se apenas o número de registros importa, você pode fazer um `count` da tabela e somente atualizar os valores se o resultado for diferente do anterior
- Adicione um campo com a data de criação ou modificação dos registros e consulte somente os registros adicionados após a última atualização da tabela
- Faça paginação, somente traga os últimos `n` registros.

## Padrão *Observer*

Um cenário mais complexo seria a implementação de um mecanismo de escuta de modificações.

Para isso, nenhum sistema externo deve modificar a base de dados diretamente. O aplicativo Android e outros clientes sempre devem atualizar a base via alguma API, como um Web Service RESTful.

Esse Web Service permitiria que clientes se conectassem a ele e recebessem atualizações de eventos. Então, sempre que um registro fosse adicionados, todos os *listeners* ou observadores seriam notificados.

A aplicação desktop, ao ser iniciado, se conectaria remotamente ao serviço e manteria essa conexão aberta, escutando por eventos.

Note que isso torna a aplicação bem mais complexa, pois precisa lidar com várias implementações diferentes, uma API REST pública e possíveis falhas de comunicação entre cliente/servidor.

Entretanto, pode ser a única saída em um cenário mais complexo, tal como onde há necessidade de atualizações instantâneas ou há muitos clientes que sobrecarregariam a base de dados com consultas.

## Cuidado para não quebrar o fluxo do usuário (usabilidade)

Cuidado ao atualizar a tela automaticamente. Se o usuário estiver olhando os registros, ou mesmo editando um deles, e tudo sumir da tela, isso vai gerar consequências negativas para alguém.

Se os dados são mutáveis, uma ideia é avisar ao usuário que há atualizações, mas somente atualizar a tabela quando ele clicar em algum botão ou link.

Se os dados são imutáveis, não há tanto problema. Apenas procure manter o foco do usuário no mesmo registro entre as atualizações. Por exemplo, se o usuário selecionou o registro escrito "banana" e, de repente, o foco está sobre "laranja", ele vai ficar perdido cada vez que a tela mudar.

Observe na tela inicial aqui do [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) como as perguntas são atualizadas para ter uma ideia sobre isso.